# C# - Send Windows Notification To Active Directory Groups or Users

Tags: c#, .net, windows, push-notification, active-directory

I want to send a windows notification to active directory users or groups. I know how users or groups are listed, retrieved in C#. However, I have no idea how to push windows notification programatically or manuelly.

How can I implement it?

Comment: This would be very difficult, if not impossible. There is no way to know which computer the user is logged into just from AD. You'd have to go through every computer in your organization to check which user is logged in. It would be *far* easier to just send them an email.

Comment: Yes, I know that sending email also works. However, we want to decrease email traffic. That's why I need to send windows push notification. Do you have a solution?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to write a custom application that will be installed on every computer in your organization that connects to a notification server and will show notifications based on the user that's logged in.